I can't parse correctly json data to enum type
So, I have Request, that looks like this:
public record UpdateSubUserRequest(
    Guid Id,
    string? Name,
    AccountType? AccountType,
    string? AccountName);

And I'm trying to pass the value of my AccountType in request payload:
{
  "id": "id",
  "name": "name",
  "accountType": "Agency"
}

In project i handle:

The question is incomplete, not duplicate .NET Core (which includes .NET 5 and later) doesn't use the obsolete JavaScriptSerializer class. Neither did ASP.NET Web API. It's unclear what the question even is though. Are all parameters empty? Only AccountType? What is AccountType? By default, simple action parameters receive values from query parameters, not the body. The body would be used automatically if a single complex type was used instead

Binding Source Parameter Inference describes how ASP.NET Core decides how to bind.
